# How to fix vuetify npm issue

Tags: node.js, vagrant

I try npm install on vagrant. I get always this error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/7app$ npm i
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN vuetifyjs-mix-extension@0.0.14 requires a peer of sass-loader@^9.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/code/7app/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.321473922
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/app/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.321473922'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-02-20T09_40_09_286Z-debug.log
```

I tried to reinstall npm and node.

If i deploy it to the test server, it works well.

Some idea what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

From npm docs :

```
The error Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm' on Windows 7 is a consequence of joyent/node#8141, and is an issue with the Node installer for Windows. The workaround is to ensure that C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm exists and is writable with your normal user account.
```

Link: https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors

Comment: You should try to run this command in the app directory. You need to change directory ( cd ) into the directory which have package.json from  there you need to run your commands like npm install or  npm i ,etc.